# Proper way for cmake to look for installed third-party include files

Tags: cmake

Pardon my very newbie question - I want cmake to look in “standard” system locations for installed third-party headers - how to do that in a "modern" portable way? The variable CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH looks promising, e.g. as a “hint” to find_file(), but on my ubuntu 18.03 system CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH just contains /usr/include/X11. Do I have to manually include “/usr/local/include” in hints to find_file()? Or is there a better way?
Thanks!

Comment: Update the CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH environment variable as appropriate

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood the doc page for CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH doc, which says "It is not intended to be modified by the project" - but I need to set it outside of the project? (i.e. cmake itself doesn't set CMAKE_* environment variables to "reasonable" values by default?)

Comment: Yeah, outside the project in one of your profile files or the like.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still missing something.
I provide my project code and cmake files to a user, and the user is expected to simply run ‘cmake ..’ from a build directory, right? So how does the user know the correct setting of CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH on their system?